# cant run grails app on Intellij idea 13

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm using **grails-2.4.0 and intellij idea 13**.
I have created my first grails app and trying to run but it errors out with:

> Error packaging application: Error occurred processing message bundles: Error starting Sun's native2ascii:  (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be helpful to lift   the content quality up

Comment: this simliar question's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081874/grails-native2ascii-error-when-i-add-a-new-property-to-message-properties) might help you